# Preg_match with variable matching integer key

Tags: php, arrays, int, preg-match, array-key

I have an array

```
$op1 = array('45'=>123, '657'=>65, '6578'=>234, '65782'=>0, '3'=>25, '756'=>156, '3445'=>178, '20924'=>92);
```

And then a variable taken from a form that I want to see if any of the array keys starts with it.

Variable: `$nr=$_POST['number'];`

Code:

```
    foreach (array_keys($op1) as $key) {
     if(preg_match('/$nr/', $key))
     {
       echo "FOUND";
     }
     else{
       echo "NOT FOUND";
     }
```

But it never finds anything in the array. 
I know that I am probably doing something wrong, but don't know what.

Comment: Variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes. This is basic PHP syntax, having nothing to do with preg_match.

Comment: If you want to check whether the key _starts_ with a number, don't forget to use the `^` anchor in the regexp.

Comment: Had to be something really basic that I wasn't noticing. Thank you.